# What would be the best practice here, where extending `enum`s would be really useful (yet impossible in java)?

Tags: java, enums

I'm making a game, and I have a set of classes: `Character` extends `MovingEntity` extends `Entity`.

The first one just has a position and a few other fields. `MovingEntity` can, as the name says, move. I used to represent this with an enum `enum State{IDLE, MOVING}`. However, I ran into a problem when I implemented `Character`, as these can attack too!

So, for a moment I was dealing with an awkward

```
Class MovingEntity extends Entity{
  public enum State{
    IDLE, MOVING;
  }
}
Class Character extends MovingEntity {
  public enum CharacterState{
    IDLE, MOVING, ATTACKING
}
```

And even more "enum overriding" when  I added more complicated characters. So I ended up switching into `public static final int` constants... But I've read here that this is considered a very bad practice (which I don't understand why, as Java's API does this (`KeyEvent.VK_stuff` are ints, JFrame's default action on close are too...).

What would be the best practice here?

Comment: Create a single `State` enum with all possible states, have each "class" of `Entity` contain a `List` (or `Set`) of valid `State`(s) for that `Entity` type.

Comment: What are these states ultimately used for? Depending on the use, could you use polymorphism to affected an object's behavior, rather than an enum?

Comment: @yshavit Well, my game's structured in a weird way: When you type a key (i.e, if you want to move), the program checks if moving is possible, if it is, it sets the state variable to `MOVING` and a game loop moves the character until some time has passed, then the state goes back to `IDLE` and so on. Also, if the downvoter would leave a comment, it would be nice.

Comment: You should probably use interfaces a lot more than it sounds you are using, for example methods should take interfaces ad parameters, not abstract classes. Perhaps changing your design to be more interface-centric would help with your enum problem too (also, "composition over inheritance", and use your IDE to generate boilerplate code for you, there's a lot of that in Java).

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the suggestions, hyde. Could explain why methods should take interfaces rather than abstract classes? Also, I don't understand what you mean by boilerplate code.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Google "java program to an interface" and "what is boilerplate code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a single enum, with all possible states. Then, each entity declares which states they support:

```
enum State{
    IDLE, MOVING, ATTACKING;
}

class Entity {
    private State[] states;

    protected Entity(State... states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

}

class Character extends Entity{
    public Character() {
        super(State.IDLE, State.MOVING, State.ATTACKING);
    }
}

class MovingEntity extends Entity{
    public MovingEntity() {
        super(State.IDLE, State.MOVING);
    }
}
```

If you create specialized characters, you could even "inherits" states from their parents.

```
class FastMovingEntity extends MovingEntity{
    public FastMovingEntity() {
        super(State.MOVING_FAST);
    }
}

class MovingEntity extends Entity{
    public MovingEntity(State... states) {
        super(...);
    }
}
```

**Why enums?**

I myself believe enums are preferred to constants because they are strongly typed and easier to read.
ex:

```
doStuff(int state);
doStuff(State state);
```

The second method speaks for itself, as far as arguments are concern, the name could be better :). Also, the boundaries are easier to validate, either you have a valid state or its null. (instead of having a range of valid ints, which must be documented through javadoc, so that the user knows how to use your method)

Finally, enum allows you to add behavior (method), which constant will not let you do.

ex:

```
enum State {
    IDLE, MOVING, ATTACKING(false), MOVING_FAST;

    private boolean someFlag;

    State(boolean someFlag) {
        this.someFlag = someFlag;
    }

    State() {
        this(true);
    }

    public boolean isSomeFlag() {
        return someFlag;
    }
}
```

Also, KeyEvent.VK_stuff uses ints, but the main reason is simply because it was there before enum even existed.

**Concerning your other question in the comments**

> every time I use a State variable inside each class, to actually
>   validate that it is a valid state, I would have to check if it's equal
>   to some value in the State[] states array?

Here's what I understand from your statement. Let's say a request is made to change state on a character. You would first need to check that the state change is supported on this character. So you would end up looping on the array all the time. Is that your question?

If so, then instead of an array in Entity, you could use a Set, with a method that returns whether the state is supported or not:

```
class Entity {
    private EnumSet<State> supportedStates;
    private State currentState;

    protected Entity(State... state) {
        states = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(state));
    }

    //Assumes you are using these values elsewhere, otherwise - private
    public boolean isStateSupported(State state){
        return supportedStates.contains(state);
    }

    public void setCurrentState(State currentState){
        if(!isStateSupported(currentState){
             throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        this.currentState = currentState;
    }
    public State getCurrentState(){
        return currentState;
    }
}
```

EDIT (June 15): I've added the method setCurrentState. With this method, you can set the current state, which first validates that that the value is supported (isStateSupported). If the list of supported states is only used internally for validation, then isStateSupported could be private, but my guess is that you should be calling this method from elsewhere for other purposes. Perhaps, the user should not have the option to set an invalid state, so your user interface would first check what are the valid states before displaying the options.
I hope I'm being clear...

Comment: I see, that's a very nice solution. I have a few questions: every time I use a  `State` variable inside each class, to actually validate that it is a valid state, I would have to check if it's equal to some value in the `State[] states` array? And also, could you address the question of why using ints for this is seen as bad practice?

Comment: I've added details to my answer on why I think enums I preferred.

Comment: + another block using a Set (instead of an array) if you need to check for supported states

Comment: An [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) would be smaller/faster/better than a `HashSet` for this purpose.

Comment: Regarding the last question, I believe you understand my question: This all began because I wanted, for example, entities to be objects that could only stay idle, Movingentities could be idle or moving, characters could be idle, moving or attacking, etc. So if I go with this option, whenever I try to set a state, I believe the correct way will be with a method with signature like `private/public void setState(State state) throws InvalidStateException`, right? Thanks for the very complete answer!

Comment: I've changed the very last code sample and some explanation, let me know if it's clear!